# Dynamic Input Checkbox on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, event-binding

I have a table of checkboxes that are being paginated through AJAX. I am trying to create an on click event for one of these new checkboxes being clicked. When it is clicked, I am going to need to an update an array of IDs based on that standard's ID.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get my Javascript to respond when the inputs are populated after the AJAX call. If I load up the inputs in the view, the on click event works fine, but if it comes back through AJAX, it isn't recognized.

I have looked through several similar issues including:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)
- [Alert after checked input checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510882/alert-after-checked-input-checkbox)

I could not find solutions to my problem from any of the above. I can't determine what is missing here.

**HTML**

```
<table summary="Standard Listing Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pl-standard-listing">
        <tr>
             <td>
                  <input checked="" name="standards[]" type="checkbox" value="8343">
             </td>
             <td>K.CC.A.1</td>
             <td>Count to 100 by ones and by tens.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery on click event**

```
$('#pl-standard-listing tr td').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    console.log("Clicked.");
    console.log(this);
});
```

**Adding the inputs for all standards from API**

```
// Select table and whipe current standards that are listed
var table = document.getElementById('pl-standard-listing');
$('#pl-standard-listing tr').remove();
for(var iCount = 0; iCount < currentStandards.length; iCount++) {
    // Check if the standard is in the list of included standards with this grade group
    if(standardIds.indexOf(currentStandards[iCount].id) === -1) {
        $('#pl-standard-listing').append($('<tr><td><input name="standards[]" type="checkbox" value="' + currentStandards[iCount].id + '" /></td><td>' + currentStandards[iCount].code + '</td><td>' + currentStandards[iCount].description + '</td></tr>'));
    } else {
        $('#pl-standard-listing').append($('<tr><td><input checked name="standards[]" type="checkbox" value="' + currentStandards[iCount].id + '" /></td><td>' + currentStandards[iCount].code + '</td><td>' + currentStandards[iCount].description + '</td></tr>'));
    }
}
```

The standards load properly in the view, I just can't get the event handler right for clicking the checkbox. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

removing `tr` `td` from on click event should work.

```
$('#pl-standard-listing').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
console.log("Clicked.");
console.log(this);
});
```